# uses undefined class despite using include

Tags: c++, class, undefined

I want to create an Instance of my game class in another class but i get an `uses undefined class` error although i include `game.h`.

Game.h

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include "Move.h"

class Game
{
  private:

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Private copy constructor
    //
    Game(const Game& original);

 public:
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Public assignment operator
    //
    Game& operator=(const Game& original);

    //Constructors
    Game ();

    //Destructor
    ~Game ();
};
#endif // _GAME_H
```

The Header where i want to create a Game Object:
Move.h

```
#ifndef MOVE_H
#define MOVE_H

#include "Game.h"

class Move : public Command
{
  private:
    Move (const Move& original);
    Move& operator=(const Move& original);

    Game m_game_;  //Error
 };
  #endif // _MOVE_H
```

Visual Studios is throwing:

```
    move.h(40): error C2079: 'Move::m_game_' uses undefined class 'Game'
```

It works if i use `Game* game;` but that's not what i need/want.

Why does the compiler gives me an error of undefined class? 
Much thanks to any help.

Comment: Why does `game.h` include `move.h`?

Comment: You are missing `;` after your `class { }`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Because i need to create a Move Object in my Game.cpp
`m_command_map_[MOVE] = new Move(MOVE);`

Comment: @TheDoctor Then you should include it in `game.cpp`.  A good pratice to get into is to only include exactly what you need in any file.  Do not rely on a file to include includes that you need.

Comment: @Holt Thanks, I know i just forgot here

Comment: Got your code compiled fine

Comment: @shrike no now i am trying to solve a link error but i hope it'll work after i solved the link error

Comment: @NathanOliver it seems your suggestion solved my problem. I would like to accept your answer :)

Comment: And why did i get 2 down votes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Game.h doesn't need to include Move.h since it isn't being used, as mentioned in the comments, if it's used in the cpp it should be included there.

The issue is probably to do with the orders of the include header files from somewhere else, say main. Consider this structure:

(I removed some of it to make it easier to see)

main.cpp file

```
#include "Game.h"
#include "Move.h"
```

Game.h file

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include "Move.h"

class Game
{
public:
    Game() {}
private:

};
#endif // _GAME_H
```

Now lets see how it looks after the Move.h file gets added into Game.h

```
    #ifndef GAME_H
    #define GAME_H

//added
    #ifndef MOVE_H
    #define MOVE_H

    #include "Game.h"

    class Move
    {
    public:
        Move() {}
    private:


        Game m_game_;
    };
    #endif // _MOVE_H

//to here

    class Game
    {
    public:
        Game() {}
    private:

    };
    #endif // _GAME_H
```

As you can see, when it gets to finally declare Game m_game_; it hasn't actually declared the class yet. Either switch the include order from where they are being included, or simply remove #include "Move.h" from Game.h since it is not being used there.

Comment: Thanks for the full explanation. it was due to the includes and now it works finally :)

Comment: I have a massive project and ran into this issue after a giant integrate. I found listing the include hierarchy helped w/ tracking down ordering